# Suspicious random letters in my website URL

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5

In my published website, it starts to show sometimes like www.xxxxxxx.com/OVQSZ/ and go to 404 - File or directory not found error where OVQSZ is a suspicious random letter showing in the website URL.

If I remove this "/OVQSZ/" and re-enter in the browser then it go to the website.

It shows this suspicious letters randomly, I dont know why it is happening since 2, 3 days.

Can anybody help me for this. Thanks

Comment: What starts to show that?  Are you publishing to a server?  Are you publishing locally or are you just hitting run?  Is it embedded in links throughout the site?

Comment: @NoMe, It shows like www.mywebsite.com/OVQSZ/ when I run my website on any client's browser. /OVQSZ/ is suspicious letters which are random sometimes it shows other serious of letters like /PjncZ/.

Comment: so you go to `www.mywebsite.com` and it redirects you to `www.mywebsite.com/ovqsz` ?  I'd check the IIS settings first.

Comment: Yes true. But it is happening since 2 or 3 days. Before it was not happening.

Comment: I still could not get clue. Anyone can help me for this please....

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue.

In order to know where the redirections come from, use

```
curl -IX GET -L http://yourdomain.com
```

For me, it showed that sometimes several 302 redirects where randomly happening before the main redirect to www. 
It is actually a Godaddy issue that was introduced a few weeks ago. They don't know when they are going to solve it.. If that's also what's happening for you I suggest you use [this solution](http://gold-thiolate.com/2013/godaddy-random-302-redirect/) or twick your 404 to redirect to your home when a random 5 letters are in the path.

Comment: Thanks @Mkou. I am using ASP.Net. it seems that I may need to rewrite URL to overcome this problem because still goDaddy did not respond well on this issue.